# Python dataframe illegal character error into 'ascii' codec decode error

Tags: python, dataframe, unicode, openpyxl

I am attempting to write a pandas dataframe to excel. Initially, I received

```
openpyxl.utils.exceptions.IllegalCharacterError
```

which I resolved with:

```
def export_file(clients):

    clients = clients.applymap(lambda x: x.encode('unicode_escape').
             decode('utf-8') if isinstance(x, str) else x)

    clients.to_excel('all_clients.xlsx')

    return()
```

Which then resulted in:

```
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)
```

However, if i resolve the unicode error I get the initial pyxl error.

I seem to be unable to resolve one error without getting the opposing error. Any suggestions?

Comment: shot in the dark (since we don't have your data): try `latin-1` instead of `utf-8`

Comment: still get the ascii error

Comment: Can you add any example data to your question?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I can say that the data is a concat of 10 different excel files and csv files. Its also all standard English and what not.

Comment: We don't want *all* the data, just a sample (can be fake data) that reproduces the problem.  Narrow it down.

Comment: Fair enough. I will submit some fake (similiar esc) data later once im off work.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of writing directly using pandas, user xlsxwrite engine. This will resolve the errors.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('all_clients.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') # engine is set here
clients.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1') # it is called here to write the excel sheet
```

> openpyxl.utils.exceptions.IllegalCharacterError will be resolved.

Comment: This did the trick for me, I would like to add that you have to import the xlsxwriter library even tho it complains about not being used. Thank you.