# How to resolve this error: openpyxl.utils.exceptions.IllegalCharacterError

Tags: python, excel, pandas, merge

I ran this simple code in Python to merge two excel sheets with an outer join on multiple keys. I keep getting the error above.

See the code below:

```
enter code here 
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

excel1 = 'Cbr_Data.xlsx'
excel2 = 'output.xlsx'

df1 = pd.read_excel(excel1)
df2 = pd.read_excel(excel2)

new_Npower = pd.merge(df1,df2, how='outer', on=['firstname', 'surname', 'residence_state', 
'residence_lga', 'program'], indicator=True)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('final_copy.xlsx')
# write dataframe to excel
new_Npower.to_excel(writer)
# save the excel

writer.save()
print('DataFrame is written successfully to Excel File.')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove illegal characters so a dataframe can write to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42306755/how-to-remove-illegal-characters-so-a-dataframe-can-write-to-excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

excel1 = 'Cbr_Data.xlsx'
excel2 = 'output.xlsx'

df1 = pd.read_excel(excel1)
df2 = pd.read_excel(excel2)

new_Npower = pd.merge(df1,df2, how='outer', on=['firstname', 'surname', 'residence_state', 
'residence_lga', 'program'], indicator=True)

new_Npower.to_excel('file_name.xlsx')
print('DataFrame is save to excel file successfully')
```

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work. However I found a solution. I installed the xlsxwriter package and resolved the issue. Thanks